# Azure pipeline shows error communicating with remote error

Tags: azure, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, azure-pipelines, appium-android

[AzurePipelineErrorImage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SFsvj.jpg)

I'm frequently getting "error communicating with remote browser. It may have died" in azure pipeline. I'm using selenium 4.1.3 version. Appium Java client 7.3.0 version. I will attach the screenshot of azure error. When the pipeline is retriggered the error is resolved. Sometimes the error is repeated. Please do help. I need to resolve this as early as possible and I'm a newbie.

Comment: Could you also add some code ?

Answer (score 0):

> When the pipeline is retriggered the error is resolved.

On the task you run the Selenium tests, you could try to set a number to the option "**`Number of retries if task failed`**" (**`retryCountOnTaskFailure`**). With this option, when the task is failed, it will automatically retry the task until it is successful or reaches the specified number of retries.

[image]

Comment: Oh ok. Thanks I will try It out. But even after retrying if the same comes? How to resolve this? I see retrying as one of the workaround.